# Image flickering in Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

In Flex4, I use an Image control.
After every 10 seconds, i am changing the image programatically using Timer.
But when the image changes, flickering occurs.
Is there any method to prevent this?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, it's hard to recommend a way to stop the flickering.  In any case, one method could be to have two Image components occupying the same space, one visible, one hidden.  When you load the next image, put it into the hidden component and then swap visibility after the new image has loaded.  This is sort of like "double-buffering".  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this along with your image Tag, ioError handler helps in identifying what error occurs when image loads, also if there is an error you can easily replace it with another image.

```
 <mx:Image ioError=""
```